# Defining a linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

> Admit that $V$ is a linear space about $\mathbb{R}$ and that $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$. Suppose that $S: U \rightarrow Y$ and $T: W \rightarrow Y$ are two linear transformations that satisfy the property:
>
> $(\forall x \in U \cap W)$ $S(x)=T(x)$
>
> Define a linear transformation $F$: $ U+W \rightarrow Y$ that matches with S for values in U and matches with T with values in W.

My thought is to choose the linear transformation $F=S+T$ because it will be the union of both transformation, right? But is this correct? Can we immediately assume this or we need to make more calculations?

Comment: If you define $F=S+T$ then you count the intersection twice: $F(x)=S(x)+T(x)=2S(x)$ for all $x\in U\cap W$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Take a basis of $U\cap W$, say $v_1, \dots , v_k$. Extend to a basis of $U$ by say $v_{k+1}, \dots , v_l$ and then extend to $U$ by $v_{l+1}, \dots , v_s$. Finally extend to basis of $V$ by $v_{s+1}, \dots , v_{n}$. Consider the matrices of $S$ and $T$ w.r.t. this basis in $V$. How can you define a new linear $F$ using these matrices?

Comment: Hi! Is it possible doing that without using matrices?

Comment: Yes, to define a linear map, you only have to specify what is does on a basis, you can do that.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really getting how to do it... I'm getting more and more confused

Comment: Define $F(v_i)=S(v_i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$, $F(v_j)=S(v_j)$ for $k+1\leq j \leq l$ and $F(v_t)=T(v_t)$ for $l+1\leq t\leq s$. It doesn't matter how you define $T(v_r)$ for $s+1\leq r \leq n$.

Comment: Please can't you be more specific on what you're vectors are and how can I take them and write my transformation. Sorry, I'm really not getting how to do this...

Comment: I did write it down in my previous comment, just carefully read what I'm saying and think about it. I cannot however give you explicit vectors and such since we have to little information for that.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "It doesn't matter how you define T(vr)T(vr) for s+1≤r≤ns+1≤r≤n."

Comment: That part is unimportant for the construction, you can take $F$ to be zero there. (Ah, I see, that should have been $F(v_r)$ for all $s+1\leq r\leq n$, not $T$.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38863/discussion-between-granger-obliviate-and-mathematician-42).